# Qualtrics experiment matrices 01

Tags: javascript, task, counting, qualtrics

Hello I am running a Qualtrics experiment using a real effort task where participants have to count the correct number of 0 present in a table ramdomly generated composed of 0 and 1. If participants have a correct answer they get 7 points otherwise they get noting. In addition they have a randomly generated amount of points that is summed up to get the score. My problem is that I cannot find how to save each of the correct answers of the participants. In my code no matter how many good answer they got the code only accounts for one, and credits accordingly 7 points, instead of how many they actually had. I need to find a solution so that all correct answers given by the participants during the time limit are recorded and credited.

here is my javascript code:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    // Définir la variable pour suivre le nombre de points gagnés
    var score = 0;
    // Définir le nombre de bonnes réponses cumulées
    var correct = 0;
    // Définir le temps imparti en secondes
    var timeLimit = 240;
    // Définir le timer
    var timer = null;
    // Définir le nombre de points bonus générés par la fonction math
    var bonusPoints = 0;
    // Définir le nombre de 0 dans le tableau
    var numberOfZeros = 0;
    // Définir le tableau pour stocker les réponses du participant
    var responses = [];
    
    // Fonction pour générer le tableau de 6x6 rempli aléatoirement de 0 et de 1
    function generateTable() {
        var table = "<table style='border-collapse: collapse; margin: auto;'>";
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            table += "<tr>";
            for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                var value = Math.round(Math.random());
                table += "<td style='border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px;'>" + value + "</td>";
                if (value === 0) {
                    numberOfZeros++;
                }
            }
            table += "</tr>";
        }
        table += "</table>";
        return table;
    }

    // Fonction pour afficher le tableau généré
    function displayTable() {
        var table = generateTable();
        jQuery("#table-container").html(table);
    }

    // Fonction pour commencer le timer
    function startTimer() {
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            timeLimit--;
            jQuery("#timer").html(timeLimit);
            if (timeLimit === 0) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                endTask();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    // Fonction pour terminer la tâche et afficher le score final
    function endTask() {
        jQuery("#table-container").html("");
        jQuery("#timer-container").html("");
        // Ajouter des points aléatoires supplémentaires au score
        bonusPoints = Math.round(Math.random() * 40);
        score = correct*7 + bonusPoints;
        jQuery("#score-container").html("");
        jQuery("#total-score-container").html("Votre gain total est de " + score + " ECU.");
        // Stocker les scores et points bonus
        Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("bonusPoints", bonusPoints);
        Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("totalScore", score);
    }

    // Fonction pour vérifier la réponse du participant
    function checkAnswer() {
        var answer = parseInt(jQuery("#answer").val());
        if (answer === numberOfZeros) {
            responses.push(7);
            correct++;
             Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("correctAnswers", correct);
        } else {
            responses.push(0);
        }
         displayTable();
        numberOfZeros = 0;
        jQuery("#answer").val("");
    }

    // Afficher le tableau au début de la tâche
    displayTable();

    // Commencer le timer au début de la tâche
    startTimer();

    // Ajouter un événement de clic pour vérifier la réponse du participant
    jQuery("#submit-button").click(function() {
        checkAnswer();
    });

});


Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function()
{
    /*Place your JavaScript here to run when the page is fully displayed*/

});

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnUnload(function()
{
    /*Place your JavaScript here to run when the page is unloaded*/

});
```